# instances where a variable gets its updated value

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree

I have a question. I am currently trying to understand how a variable is updated/changed. I am working with a binary search tree and I get how the pointer are used aswell as the dereferencing in the parameter to access a classes variable.
...

```
class BST {
public:
  int value;
  BST *left;
  BST *right;

  BST(int val);
  BST &insert(int val);
};

int findClosestValueInBst(BST *tree, int target);
int findClosestValueInBstHelper(BST *tree, int target, int closest);

int findClosestValueInBst(BST *tree, int target){
  return findClosestValueInBstHelper(tree, target, tree->value);
}

int findClosestValueInBstHelper(BST *tree, int target, int closest) {
  // Write your code here.
  if(abs(target - closest) > abs(target - tree->value)){
    closest = tree->value;
  } 
  if(target < tree ->value && tree->left != nullptr){
    return findClosestValueInBstHelper(tree->left, target, closest);
  } 
  else if(target > tree->value && tree -> right != nullptr){
    return findClosestValueInBstHelper(tree->right, target, closest);
  }
  else {
    return closest;
  }

}
```

...
I see that the variable 'closest' has a direct value change in the findClosestValueInBstHelper(). I know that I have to physically put a value for closest in the paraeter so that the function will run. So what im asking is to describe the instances where the values change. please.

Comment: Variables change when you assign to them, like the example you mentioned. Variables can also be initialised, which is when the get their initial value (so it's not really a change). It's a simple concept so I'm feeling that you are misunderstanding something fundamental, but I'm not sure what it is.

Comment: And why don't you make your functions like ('findClosestValueInBst') members of your class?

Comment: You use the phrase 'direct value change', does that mean you think there is some kind of 'indirect value change', is that what you are asking about?

Comment: probably because i just simply do not know these things and Im fairly new to coding and am currently taking a OOP course in c++. I thought i could say change but i guess your right.

Comment: So, maybe the recursion is confusing you, it's a common problem. Here's how it works. every time you call `findClosestValueInBstHelper` a new `closest` variable is created. Every call to `findClosestValueInBstHelper` has it's own variables. It's not true that variables are shared somehow between different calls to `findClosestValueInBstHelper`.

Comment: Each time `closest` is assigned, its value will be updated.  However, the argument `closest` is passed to `findClosestValueInBstHelper()` BY VALUE, which COPIES the value passed by the caller, so any updates of `closest` in the function affect the copy and not the variable/value passed by the caller.  That is true everywhere you call it, so `return findClosestValueInBstHelper(tree, target, tree->value)` in `findClosestValueInBst()` does not update `tree->value` and (in the second `if`) the recursive `return findClosestValueInBstHelper(tree->left, target, closest)` does not update `closest`.